# Playing Audio in .NET Core Console App C#

Tags: c#, .net, audio, console-application, .net-core

My goal is to play an audio clip (any format really) in a .NET Core 1.1 Console App for C#.

I've tried different libraries like IrrKlang, PortAudioSharp and neither of them work. They either requires an external DLL like mscorlib.dll, or simply isn't compatible.

What choices are there, that isn't too low-level? I need a simple and easy "Play Audio" - "Stop Audio".

I appreciate all the help that I can get!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a discussion about this in the official repo.

https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/74#issuecomment-232456726

Looks like there is no easy and ready to go solution for this yet. .NET core was written from scratch. So any library to be compatible with .NET Core, it has to be rewritten from scratch too or at least modified to be compatible with .NET Core. ManagedBass library could be useful to you. But as described in the forum, it is still a P/Invoke binding to low level library.